# spring jpa setup cannot update database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I'm a long time reader, first time poster.

Essentially I'm writing a web app based on the [spring 3 showcase](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/).

Subsequently I plugged in the ability to write to a database based on [this tutorial](http://paulszulc.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/jpa-2-0-and-spring-3-0-with-maven/).

My integration tests that test all the ORM stuff appear happy however when I deploy my project to tomcat and attempt to do a db update via the website the database does not update!

Configuration:

appContext.xml

```
<!-- holding properties for database connectivity / -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<!-- enabling annotation driven configuration / -->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="wcpackage" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="wctemplatePU"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}" />
```

jdbc.properties

```
jpa.database=gm
jpa.showSql=true
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gm?user=gmuser&password=gmuser
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="wctemplatePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Code that should commit to the db

```
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
protected Sequence persistGame(PGNGame game) {
    Sequence seq = new Sequence();
    seq.setType(SequenceType.GAME);
    seq.setEvent(game.getTag("Event"));
    seq.setSite(game.getTag("Site"));

            ...

    sequenceDao.persist(seq);

    return seq;
}
```

SequenceDao is essentially

```
public abstract class JpaDao<K, E> implements Dao<K, E> {
protected Class<E> entityClass;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public JpaDao() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

public void persist(E entity) { entityManager.persist(entity); }

public void remove(E entity) { entityManager.remove(entity); }

public E findById(K id) { return entityManager.find(entityClass, id); }
}
```

I get no errors of any sort I can see in the console/logs.  What am I doing wrong?

One thing I notice when I crank up the hibernate logging to DEBUG

```
DEBUG:org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 12975078282
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
    DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

TRACE log is

```
DEBUG:org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
DEBUG: org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 12975085724
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.IdentifierValue - id unsaved-value: 0
TRACE: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - transient instance of: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player
TRACE: org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener - saving transient instance
TRACE: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - saving [net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player#<null>]
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player
TRACE: org.hibernate.event.def.WrapVisitor - Wrapped collection in role: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player.sequenceList
DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player.sequenceList
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction - cascading to persist: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.IdentifierValue - id unsaved-value: 0
TRACE: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - transient instance of: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence
TRACE: org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener - saving transient instance
TRACE: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - saving [net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence#<null>]
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence
TRACE: org.hibernate.event.def.WrapVisitor - Wrapped collection in role: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence.commentList
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.IdentifierValue - id unsaved-value: 0
DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence.commentList
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - done cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence.commentList
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Sequence
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - done cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player.sequenceList
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: net.samuelbergin.gm.model.Player
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
TRACE: org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - closing session
```

Entity definition

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sequences")
public class Sequence {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SequenceType type;
    private String event;
    private String site;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    private int round;
    private String result;
    private String eco;
    private String description;
    private String moves;
    @ManyToOne
    private Player whitePlayer;
    @ManyToOne
    private Player blackPlayer;
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="sequenceComments",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="sequence_fk")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="comment_fk")})
    private List<Comment> commentList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
        ...
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fileupload")
public class FileUploadController {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    @Autowired private SequenceService sequenceService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws IOException {
        //TODO: parse pgn
        List<PGNGame> pgnGameList;
        String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        try {
            pgnGameList = PGNProcessor.parse(file.getInputStream());

            sequenceService.createSequences(pgnGameList);

            String message = "File '" + filename + "' uploaded successfully";
            model.addAttribute("message", new Message(MessageType.success, message));

        } catch (PGNProcessorException ppe) {
            logger.error("Failed to process "+filename, ppe);
            model.addAttribute("message", new Message(MessageType.error, "Failed to process "+filename+".  Reason: "+ppe.getMessage()));
        }
        // else whole html pg is rendered instead of just a div to update
        model.addAttribute("ajaxRequest", AjaxUtils.isAjaxUploadRequest(request));  
    }
}
```

Service

```
public class JpaSequenceService implements SequenceService {

    ...

public List<Sequence> createSequences(List<PGNGame> gameList) {
    List<Sequence> seqList = new ArrayList<Sequence>();
    for (PGNGame game : gameList) {
        Sequence seq = persistGame(game);
        seqList.add(seq);
    }
    return seqList;
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
protected Sequence persistGame(PGNGame game) {
        /*...as above...*/
}
```

Comment: What's calling the `persistGame()` method?

Comment: Yeah that's definitely getting called.  My Controller injects a Service that contains the persistGame() method.

Comment: All looks fine. Try clean build

Comment: Nope still same problem.  I'm running via Maven under an embedded Tomcat server (mvn tomcat:run).  That shouldn't make any difference though I wouldn't think.

Comment: @SamB please show the controller, and the service (the relevant pieces at least)

Comment: @Bozho added Controller and Service to the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Transactional` only works when its placed on a public method that is invoked from other objects (and not within the same object).

Transactions are handled by creating a proxy around the object. Calls from outside are intercepted by the proxy, and hence a transaction is started. Calls within the same object are not intercepted by the proxy.

So in your case:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public List<Sequence> createSequences(List<PGNGame> gameList) {
```

Note that it is generally a good practice to wrap units of work within a transaction. Even if your code worked, it would be unnecessarily opening and closing multiple transactions. Unless you wanted to persist each game individually. If this is the case, then either iterate the list in the controller, or create a new class that will save the games.

As Augusto noted, if you use `proxy-target-class="true"` for your proxies, you may be able to make an internal invocation start a transaction. However I'd discourage that, because you are becoming dependent on this configuration option, and if you change in the future for some other reason, you might waste time finding why existing functionality stopped working.

Comment: Bozho, that's not 100% correct, if you configure spring to use cglib to weave the classes, a public 'non-transactional' method can call another method on the same class that is marked with @transactional and spring will start a unit of work. I'm not sure if it works with private methods, but for sure it works with public, package (default) and protected methods.

Comment: @Augusto you are right, but I omitted that option on purpose - it is not a good idea to rely on a given behaviour based on the proxying strategy. In two monghts you may change the strategy, or you may use `<aop:scoped-proxy>` for some other reason, and then suddenly some functionality will stop working. That's why I think it's best to make it work in the general case.

Comment: Putting the @Transaction on the public method, createSequence(), has fixed the problem.  That's fantastic!  Thanks so much for your time guys!